# I get an error when I end the if statement with a concluding else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, scope, nested

I wrote this Python code that would check a list and return `True` if two items in the list next to each other are of the same value:

```
def samer(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1): 
        if (nums[i]) == (nums[i+1]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Result 1:

```
>>> samer([1,3,44,5,5,8])
False
```

This is where I'm puzzled because I feel it should return `True`.

Result 2:

```
>>> samer([3,3,49,93,5,8])
True
```

It only returns `True` if the first and second number in the list is `True`.

The solution:

```
def samer(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1): 
        if (nums[i]) == (nums[i+1]):
            return True
    return False
```

The above code works well, so my question is since the `else` statement indented under the `if` condition's purpose is to return `False` if no number in the list is next to each other in the process of the `for` loop, why do I still get `False` in Result 1?

Is it that it doesn't loop again after checking the first two boxes and why is that since it's the purpose of the `for` loop to go over each iteration and then check for the conditions?

Comment: A function *ends* when it returns.

Comment: In the first code, your loop will **always** run once! if the first two numbers are similar it will return `True`, otherwise `False`. I think the best way for you to learn from this is to use [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and see exactly what happens step-by-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function returns, that's it. The function is done, over, finished..

Since you're returning either true or false when checking each and every element, you really only check the *first* time through the loop (elements one and two), as you observe.

You should return true if a match is found and only return false at the end, when you've checked *everything* and, therefore, *no* matches are found. That code is already in your question, the bit under `The solution`.

Answer (score 0):

So to chip in here, once that first iteration check occurs, we know that it's going to be returning `False` as the first two elements are not the same and the program ends there. If you want to *really* see that this is the case, make use of `print()` built-in function to see what's going on everytime the element is iterated within the `for` loop:

Like this:

```
 def samer(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1): 
       if (nums[i]) == (nums[i+1]):
          print(True)
       else:
          print(False)

 ### adding a main method is always a good idea for clarity.   
 if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(samer([1,3,44,5,5,8]))
```

Output is this:

```
 False
 False
 False
 True 
 False
```

See it returned `True` for the 3th element as they are equal and next to each other.

But with the way you had it structured in the first example it does return `False` as it hit the roadblock once it checked and saw that the first iteration were not equal to each other and thus returned `False`.

```
 def samer(nums):
   for i in range(0,len(nums)-1): 
      if (nums[i]) == (nums[i+1]):
        return True
      else:
        return False

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(samer([1,3,44,5,5,8]))
```

Output is:

```
False
```

With your *solution* approach which is great, the loop only 'terminates' when it *really* cannot find a match (same two numbers), it will return `False` without depending on a `else` statement. So if it finds a match then it will return `True` which is does and then stops iterating and exits the program.